# $\int_A \sum_{i=2}^n\left(\frac{x_i^3}{2}-x_{i-1} x_i^2\right)+\frac{x_1^3}{2}-x_1^2 x_n$ $A:=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid\|x\|=1\right\}$

Tags: integration

$\int_A \sum_{i=2}^n\left(\frac{x_i^3}{2}-x_{i-1} x_i^2\right)+\frac{x_1^3}{2}-x_1^2 x_n$ mit $A:=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid\|x\|=1\right\}$,

$||x||=\sqrt{x_1^2+....+x_n^2}$ I think this can express with the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$.
But i dont know how to solve the integral.
Can someone help me?